# A present day adjective for "cannot be taken away"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that denotes the fact that something cannot be taken away (or deprived of) once it is acquired (like an experience) as in:

> Your experiences cannot be taken away from you, man, they stay with you forever.

I was thinking of something along the lines of: "experiences, as a rule, are *indivestable* so much unlike rights and dignities", but only in a more modern non-obsolete kind of way (very few people in my control group actually knew what "indivestable" meant). I need this stuff for an ad, meaning it must be easily understood by both the young and the old, the bright and the dim, the rich and the poor, well, you catch my drift, right.

I am in need of a word that says that once you acquire something, through investing time and effort, it is yours forever, no matter what it just cannot be taken away from you. It is not granted to you by anyone, and it is something you must "take" to have.

Comment: How about _permanent_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *indelible* often is used in such a way.  From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indelible#Adjective), *indelible* has senses  “incapable of being annulled [eg] *They are endued with indelible power from above*”,  “having the quality of being difficult to remove, wash away, blot out, or efface”, and “incapable of being canceled, lost, or forgotten”. For example, “This experience will leave an indelible and delectable memory for you”.

Also consider *ingrained* in its sense “present in the essence of a thing”  ([en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ingrained#Adjective)) and *[branded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/branded)*, past participle of brand, using the latter word in its sense (from [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brand#Verb)) of “To make an indelible impression on the memory or senses”.  For example, “This experience will be branded on your heart”.

Answer (score 4):

In the US at least, *everyone* -- man and woman, young and old, rich and poor -- is familiar with the word ***inalienable*** (or ***unalienable***), if only from a [single source](http://www.archives.gov/exhibits/charters/declaration_transcript.html):

> *We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain **unalienable** Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness.*

Now, inalienable means both "can't be *given up* **or** *taken away*", but your two examples lead me to think you're looking for a word with a stronger sense of the latter ("*can't be **taken away**, but possible to surrender*"); in that case, you may consider "***irrevocable***" and synonyms.

From [Macmillan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irrevocable):

> ***irrevocable***: *impossible to revoke; not capable of being changed*

<sup>*And what do **I** think about "*untakeawayable*"? I can only comment that using it would influence my decision to click on your ad. :)*</sup>

Comment: I am in need of a word that says that once you acquire (an experience) something through investing time and effort it is yours forever no matter what it cannot be taken away from you. It is not granted to you by any one and it is something you must "take" to have. My only beef with "inalienable" is that it doesn't imply that you have to take "yours" to have it. Divest (antonym of invest) implies that some one takes away something from you you got through investing time and effort. I hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: That makes sense; you'll get better targeted answers if you include that detail in your question.

Comment: @user74809 I believe your question to be based on a false premise - the notion that anything can last forever. As Daniel Defoe observed in 1726, the only things certain in life are death and taxes.

Comment: And that taxes seem to come before death...

Comment: @user74808 [And after](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_tax). And WS2, the slogan "*Diamonds are for until she dies*" just doesn't have the same ring to it.

Answer (score 3):

For a casual language advertisement you could say "Your experiences are *for keeps*."

Answer (score 2):

Something that cannot be taken away is similar to something that cannot be removed.

> Your experiences are **irremovable**

Comment: Not bad, not bad at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's so obvious that I'd normally put this as a comment, but won't **secure** do?

There's also **fixed**.

Answer (score 0):

I think *[deep-rooted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deep-rooted)* may convey the idea:

> - Firmly implanted; well-established: deep-rooted ideas.

Your experiences are so deep-rooted that they will stay with you forever.

Comment: Image an ad for a TV that reads in small font: "We don't sell  TVs we sell experiences" then right under the above-mentioned caption in large capital letters the following is written: "Experiences are deep-rooted"... "Experiences are forever" more like it. The problem is TVs' manufacturer wants go with "undivestable" which, in Korean, is quite common and non-existent in English to say the least. I think I'm going to have to scratch the whole "undivestable" thing and come up with something English folks have a shot to get the elegance and beauty of. Well, at least I can say I've tried.

Comment: @user74809, if you want a common, folksy way of saying "*forever*", try "***for life***": "TVs break, but memories are *for life*".

Comment: I don't really think that the whole "experience/memories" thing is going to play out nicely in English. I've actually said so from the get-go, but did they listen to me, of course they didn't they never do... Now I have to get them to revamp the whole campaign to suit and befit English culture and rack up a huge bill in the process. Ain't life grand ,huh...

Answer (score 0):

**Irretractable**- This fits nicely with the rights and dignities because it suggests someone granting something but then reneging.

**Permanent**- Your control group will definitely recognize this one.